# Can I have both dedicated Graphic Cards (different brand) plugged in to mobo and switch over anytime I want?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, dual-gpu

I have `NVIDIA Ge Force GTX 980 TI` which is not the best but enough to play my favorite game CS GO.. But as I am coding on the computer 99% of the time as a full stack developer, I feel very comfortable with 6 monitors while working. As there is no `NVIDIA` card (as of now) which supports the 6 monitors, I bought `VisionTek Radeon 7750 2GB GDDR5 6M` which supports 6 monitors with no issue but of course it is not for gaming and kind of makes me sad every time I see my `GTX 980 TI` is just sitting there with no use.

I was wondering if there is any way if I plug both graphic cards to the MOBO, could I switch (either on windows start up or during runtime) any graphic card as I want?

PS: my MOBO is Asus X99-PRO/USB 3.1 Motherboard, Intel Socket 2011-v3 with i7-6950X CPU

If not, would it be possible with any kind of adapter?

(Basically, I just want to be able to use my `GTX 980 TI` when I want to play game, and also able to use `Radeon` when I am coding. )

- I hope this does not sound like "I want a Samsung S20 Ultra with an IOS in it!"

Comment: If your motherboard has 2 PCIEx16 slots, you can use 2 GPU's given that they are wide enough to fit 2 GPU's.

Comment: thank @NiallUK - it says 40-Lane CPU-
3 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x16, x16/x16, x16/x16/x8) *1
28-Lane CPU-
3 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 ( x16, x16/x8, x16/x8/x4) *2
1 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (x4 mode) *3
2 x PCIe 2.0 x1 (x1 mode) *3
on manufacturers website and I am able to plug both of them (no space issue) I am just not sure if that would damage or would be supported to switch via some software

Comment: It wouldn't be damaged because they are designed for multi-use purposes. Give it a go and see what happens. You don't know until you try!

Comment: to be honest  I already tried and my PC started with no issues, but I was only able to see one of them on Windows. So I was wondering if this is not supported at all, or I just dont know how to do it. thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: Are your drivers installed? Did you check in the BIOS if it's recognised?

Comment: correct. Both drivers installed but cant see on BIOS - also updated my bios version to make sure it is not because of the older bios version